# ListView onClick

Tags: android

I'm trying to do something very simple: create a frequently asked questions listview, and when a question is clicked, the answer appears in a textview. I created two string arrays for questions and answers, and each element is listed as an item. There are 5 q's and 5 a's. Right now the questions are being displayed correctly in a listview, but the onclick isn't working. What is wrong??

```
package freq.asked;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FreqActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //displays all elements of questions array in listview
            setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.array.questions, R.layout.main));
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, TextView v, int position, long id) {
        String[] ans = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.answers);
        for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
                    //should display answer to question in textview
            v.setTag(ans[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where's the textView you want to change? Is it in the same layout? or in another activity? don't use the TextView v.

Comment: Try to print log insted of textview to check item click working or not.

Comment: You can also Override item click method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are using the wrong method, try `onListItemClick()` instead:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
```

---

An example:

```
public class FreqActivity extends ListActivity {
    String[] ans;
    String[] questions;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ans = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.answers);
        questions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.questions);
        //displays all elements of questions array in listview
        setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(),
                R.array.questions, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1));
    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        ((TextView) v).setText(questions[position] + ": " + ans[position]);
    }
}
```

Notice that you don't need to get the `ans` every time the user clicks a row, you only need to do it once in `onCreate()`

---

If you only wan to start a new Activity after clicking a "question" use this in `onListItemClick()`:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, AnswerActivity.class);
i.putExtra("answer", ans[position]);
startActivity(i);
```

You can read about how to read this data here: [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2091465/1267661)

Comment: thank you, but that is not quite right. i think what that does is set the question in the listview to the text of the answer.

Comment: Well, you only specified "when a question is clicked, the answer appears in a textview". How about this? You can add any format that you want, but I used `": "` as a simple spacer.

Comment: sorry, i meant that it should open a new page with a textview in it, and display the text of the answer. but i think i can figure that out!

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following replacing the method onItemClick,

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
}
```